# Given ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=g\left(x,y\right)+h\left(x,y\right)$ Can we get the general solution separately from $g(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve for the general solution to the ordinary differential equation of the form:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=g\left(x,y\right)+h\left(x,y\right)$$
Can the general solution y(x) be found by solving separately:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=g\left(x,y\right)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{dy}{dx}=h\left(x,y\right)\ $$
So that the general solution would have the form
$$y(x)=\ y_{g(x,y)}(x)\ +\ y_{h(x,y)}(x)$$

For example:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y}-x^3sec\left(y\right)$$

Solving for general solution separately:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-x^3sec\left(y\right)\ \ \ \ (2)$$
Then the respective solutions are:
$$y_{\left(1\right)}\ =\ \ 2\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2}+d}$$
$$y_{\left(2\right)}\ =\ \sin^{-1}({\frac{-x^4}{4}}\ +e)$$
So that $$ y\left(x\right)\ =\ 2\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2}+d}+\sin^{-1}({\frac{-x^4}{4}}\ +e)$$

Is this process even allowed?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: No, that is not possible. Numerical methods exist that alternate two vector fields so that the overall solution is for the sum of the vector fields, but that does not apply to the exact solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am yet to learn numerical methods for ODE's so I cannot yet comprehend your overall statement.

Comment: @MarioGonzalez , pardon for not being clear. I am asking if the process I posted is allowed. Thank you

Comment: Check the answer by differentiating

Comment: @Sal I'm afraid that checking by differentiating and eliminating $y$ is unimaginably difficult.

Comment: Take the basic example $f(x,y)=-g(x,y)=y$ this gives you constants for general solution to be compared to $e^{\pm x}$ for separated solutions. Even for simple example this is non linear, for $f=g=y$ you get $e^{2x}$ compared to $e^x$ the initial sum has turned into a multiplication by integration.